# Перенаправление потока

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать в С++ чтобы при вводе на клавиатуре чисел на консоли отображались звёздочки или что-нибудь другое?

Answer (score 1):

Не понял, причем здесь перенаправление.

Если читаете символы с клавиатуры и хотите, чтобы вместо эха были звездочки просто читайте вызывая getch() (она не ждет нажатия ENTER) и пишите putchar('*') вместо введенного символа.